# Setting up Sage 200C

Tags: sage-erp

I have setup and installed sage 200c but my computer is a domain member and not a workgroup I have added the user into the sageadministrator group but yet I am still presented with this dialog. The same happens for the sageuser group I created.

[image]

My Admin group is called Sage200Administrators
And as you can see I am part of the domain group but my computer is also part of my company domain group is sage somehow getting confused.

[image]

This is my services account Sage200Services.

[image]

To User Accounts

[image]

You can see all my sage services are started ok

[image]

Comment: Hi David, is you Sage200Administrators group a local machine group or a domain user group?

Comment: @DotNetHitMan the machine is part of domain yes that is correct. Is there a proper sage forum this seems to be more to do with sage maths ?

Comment: No, you're ok to post things about Sage 200 here. There are official Sage forums, yes, but you have to be an accredited partner to use them. I am pretty sure that you need to be using domain users. It's not like older versions where local users could be added.